# How i can delete wrong links?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have problems with parsing when I want to get a response from the server - I suddenly found that the links are wrong. When i try remove all of links with ends .txt:

```
out1 = ['https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\q\\T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
                    'https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1248.1-200107-I!!SUM-HTM-E.htm',
                    'https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\q\\T-REC-Q.1238.4-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
                    'https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\x\\T-REC-X.42-200003-S!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
                    'https://www.itu.int/rec/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-X.51-198811-I',]
```

I receive next print:

```
a = ['https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1248.1-200107-I!!SUM-HTM-E.htm',
        'https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\x\\T-REC-X.42-200003-S!!SUM-TXT-E.txt']
```

My code:

```
for ii in out1:
    if ii.find('.txt'):
       out1.remove(ii)
print(out1)
```

How i can delete wrong links with .txt? Thank you
Update, i was writing:

```
        r_list = []
        for ii in out1:
            d = re.sub(r'http\S+txt', '', ii)
            r_list.append(d)
        res = list(filter(lambda x: x, r_list))
        print(res)
```

Comment: try to iterate each link and if `link.endswith('txt')` do your things to it.

Comment: if the endswith() function doesn't help, in case it doesn't end with the extension of the file, you could try to use a regular expression. import re and then create a regex.

Comment: I will try with a regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned `regex` is not necessary but if you like to use it, try to search for the ending:

```
import re
[l for l in out1 if not re.search(r'\.txt$',l)]
```

Without `regex` simply using `endswith()` will do the same job:

```
[l for l in out1 if not l.endswith('.txt')]
```

Both will give you a cleaned list:

```
['https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1248.1-200107-I!!SUM-HTM-E.htm','https://www.itu.int/rec/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-X.51-198811-I']
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can check `.txt` and remove using `continue` keyword.

```
out1 = ['https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\q\\T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
        'https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1248.1-200107-I!!SUM-HTM-E.htm',
        'https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\q\\T-REC-Q.1238.4-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
        'https://www.itu.int./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\\rec\\x\\T-REC-X.42-200003-S!!SUM-TXT-E.txt',
        'https://www.itu.int/rec/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-X.51-198811-I',]


for i  in out1:
    #print(i)
    if '.txt' in i:
        continue
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1248.1-200107-I!!SUM-HTM-E.htm
https://www.itu.int/rec/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-X.51-198811-I
```